# $.mobile.loadPage() not Working

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

`$.mobile.loadPage('view-video');` is not working, and i have sample code bellow. Please help me to resolve this issue.

I am getting the Alert **"Function Triggered"**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div data-role="page" id="index">
  <div data-role="header">
    <h1>Welcome To My Homepage</h1>
  </div>

  <div data-role="main" class="ui-content">
    <p>I Am Now A Mobile Developer!!</p>
    <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="loadVideo">Load Video</a>
  </div>

  <div data-role="footer">
    <h1>Footer Text</h1>
  </div>
</div> 

<div data-role="page" id="view-video">
  <div data-role="main" class="ui-content">
    Your Video Will be Here.
  </div>
</div> 

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).on('click', '.loadVideo', function(e){
        alert('Function Triggered');
        $.mobile.loadPage('view-video');
    });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First the [documentation says](http://api.jquerymobile.com/jquery.mobile.loadpage/)

> Note: jQuery.mobile.loadPage is deprecated as of jQuery Mobile 1.4.0 and will be removed in 1.5.0. Use the [pagecontainer](http://api.jquerymobile.com/pagecontainer/) widget's [load()](http://api.jquerymobile.com/pagecontainer/#method-load) method instead.

Got it [working in this Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bnkb0fuk/4/) with JavaScript. Instead of `$(':mobile-pagecontainer').pagecontainer('load', "view-video);` it have to be `$(':mobile-pagecontainer').pagecontainer('change', "#view-video");`! ([**change**](http://api.jquerymobile.com/pagecontainer/#method-change) instead of **load** and with **#** cause it's an id)

See [jQuery Mobile Demos](https://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.4.5/intro/) for detail instructions.
Important is that each page has it `data-role="page"` attribute => [jQuery Mobile Tutorial](https://www.w3schools.com/jquerymobile/jquerymobile_pages.asp)

Comment: Now i have changed the code to $(":mobile-pagecontainer").pagecontainer("load", "view-video.php"); still its not working

Comment: **view-video.php** is wrong, it have to be the id of the "page" so without **.php** => edited my answer

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/bnkb0fuk/2/ please have a look

Comment: See my updated answer with full working example

Comment: The problem is i want to load view-video page via javascript, not with <a href="#view-video">View-Video</a>

Comment: You didn't specify this in your question but anyway now updated again my answer with working solution to do with javascript.

Comment: my question was $.mobile.loadPage('view-video'); this is not working, because i want to load the page with javascript, not with <a href=""></a> tag.